# Python 3 and Vagrant without Virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, vagrant, virtualenv

I want to set up a Ubuntu VM with Python 3. All the resources I've seen so far want me to use virtualenv but I don't see the point since I only want one Python (I don't care about 2.7 in other words).

Is there a way to do this where I can just ssh into the VM and my environment is all set up for me?

Comment: You can search for a suitable box on [Atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search). Is this for development or runtime usage? You may be better off searching on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) if this is for runtime only.

Answer (score 1):

There are no Ubuntu *releases* that default to Python 3. Maybe in the future, but as of right now, you will have to workaround the fact that Ubuntu ships with Python 2 as the default, Python 3 is available.

So pick a release of Ubuntu that you like, and then:

1. Upgrade the system (`sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade -y`)
2. Install the build toolchain (`sudo apt install build-essential -y`)
3. Install Python3 (`sudo apt install python3 python3-dev -y`)
4. Switch your user to Python3 as the default; I would recommend using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) for this.

Once you do this, then for your user Python will default to Python 3, but for other system utilities, Python 2 will still be available.

It might just be easier to use the [default Python docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) since its allows you to easily switch versions (it is based on debian).

Comment: Is there a non-ubuntu release that defaults to Python 3? I'm getting errors doing it the way you suggest and I don't want to chase them down the rabbit hole.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no Linux distributions that default to Python 3; thus the easiest way is to use docker. If you want to stick with a full fat distribution, consider using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

Comment: Hmm, `pyenv` looks similar to `virtualenv` and `rbenv`. This is the kind of thing I want to avoid. I guess Python 3 isn't mainstream enough yet, kind of a bummer.

Comment: `pyenv` is the Python equivalent for `rbenv`, it is not the same thing as `virtualenv`.

Comment: Right but they all have the same problem from my point of view, they make it hard to set up a clean environment.